# Rsyslog - How to disable udp syslog?

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog, unix-sockets, rsyslogd

Currently `rsyslog` is listening on both UDP socket and UNIX socket, as shown below:

```
[root@machine ~]# netstat -ap | grep rsyslog
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59018           0.0.0.0:*                           268440/rsyslogd     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    74163705 268440/rsyslogd      
[root@machine ~]# 
[root@machine ~]#
[root@machine ~]# 
[root@machine ~]# 
[root@machine ~]# uname -a
Linux machine.abc.com 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 14 10:36:03 EST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@machine ~]#
```

---

Configuration changes required for rsyslogd's UDP syslog reception is unclear. `/etc/rsyslog.conf` has no such changes, as shown below:

```
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf 

$OmitLocalLogging on

$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state

authpriv.*                      @some_remote_machine.abc.com
```

where `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` has following entry:

```
$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog
```

---

For security reasons, goal is to disable rsyslogd's UDP syslog reception

strace shows `socket()` invoked only once on starting `rsyslogd`

```
socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
```

Below are the details related to udp:

```
[root@machine ~]#  rsyslogd -d 2>&1|grep -i udp
4078.341962469:main thread    : tplAddLine processing template 'RSYSLOG_omudpspoofDfltSourceTpl'
4078.350580740:main thread    : Template: Name='RSYSLOG_omudpspoofDfltSourceTpl' 
[root@machine ~]# rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 8.24.0, compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64

See http://www.rsyslog.com for more information.
[root@machine ~]#
```

---

How to configure rsyslog to disable UDP syslog reception? Because we have syslog-ng installed...

Answer (score 1):

Disable the loading of imudp module.  Example below.

#### Confirm is currently using UDP

```
# netstat -ap|grep rsyslog
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:syslog          0.0.0.0:*                           17076/rsyslogd
udp6       0      0 [::]:syslog             [::]:*                              17076/rsyslogd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1074728  17076/rsyslogd
#
```

#### Check config file

```
# grep -i udp /etc/rsyslog.conf
# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
#
```

#### Disable UDP and restart rsyslog

```
# sed -i 's/\$ModLoad imudp/#\$ModLoad imudp/' /etc/rsyslog.conf
# systemctl restart rsyslog
#
```

#### Confirm now only using TCP

```
# netstat -ap|grep rsyslog
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1073845  16982/rsyslogd
#
```

Comment: It is already disabled

Comment: Perhaps enabled in `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf` ?  If still no luck try updating question with output of `rsyslogd -d 2>&1|grep -i udp` ?  Also add which version of `rsyslogd` in play, via `rsyslogd -v` ?

Comment: Query updated with requried details

Comment: Got the hint. Disabling `$ModLoad imjournal` disabled UDP port. But, what are the side affects? Config file is in the query

Answer (score 0):

I've had some issues running both `rsyslog` and `syslog-ng` on RHEL 7.5, and even trying to stop or kill process did not help. So I decided to delete `rsyslog`.